# Como convertir array a json en base a los elementos del array

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Yo tengo el siguiente array plano:

```
let data = [
    ["0000001", "PAUL", "Y", "PELUCHE", "DRAKE", "DOG"],
    ["0000002", "ECHEBEL", "Y", "CAT", ""],
    ["0000003", "NANCY", "Y", "FERRET", "HAMSTER", ""]
]
```

Y necesito convertir este array en json, según la n cantidad de mascotas su ayuda por favor
La funcion

```
let orderData = data.reduce((a, b) => {
let id = b[0]
id = parseInt(b[0])
let name = b[1]
let pets = b.splice(3)

if (!a.hasOwnProperty(id)) a[id] = {
  name: "",
  pets: []
}

a[id].name = name

a[id].pets.push(...pets.filter(x => x !== ""))

return a
}, {})
console.log(orderData)

Object.keys(orderData).forEach(key => {

let objeto = orderData[key]

objeto.pets.forEach(pet => console.log(objeto.name, pet))
})
```

Pero eso está mal, porque no me permite convertir la identificación a int, y aunque imprime la cantidad, la devuelve como una matriz plana y me gustaría que devuelva algo como esto, por favor, también, que está instanciando desde la identificador, ¿cómo incluyo la identificación también dentro del mismo objeto js y hago algo como esto?

Hay alguna manera de retornar este array de arriba, de esta forma? en Json.

```
{"id":1, "name":"PAUL","PET1":"PELUCHE"},
{"id":1, "name":"PAUL","PET2":"DRAKE"},
{"id":1, "name":"PAUL","PET3":"DOG"},
{"id":2, "name":"ECHEBEL","PET1":"CAT"},
{"id":3, "name":"NACY","PET1":"FERRET" },
{"id":3, "name":"NANCY","PET2":"HAMSTER"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let data = [
    ["0000001", "PAUL", "Y", "PELUCHE", "DRAKE", "DOG"],
    ["0000002", "ECHEBEL", "Y", "CAT", ""],
    ["0000003", "NANCY", "Y", "FERRET", "HAMSTER", ""]
];

function procesar(datos){
  
  let resultado = [];
  
  datos.forEach(arreglo => {
  
    let correlativoMascota = 1;
    // recorrer todos los peluches empezando en la posición 3
    for(i = 3 ; i < arreglo.length; i++){
      if(arreglo[i].length > 0){
        // si hay un valor en la posición i agregarlo al arreglo
        // de resultados
        let obj = {
                  id : parseInt(arreglo[0]), // convertir id a número
                  name : arreglo[1] // agregar nombre
             }
        obj[`pet${correlativoMascota++}`] = arreglo[i]; // agregar    propiedad pet{n}
        resultado.push(obj);
      }
    }
  
  
  
  });
  
  return resultado;
}

console.log(procesar(data));
```

Comment: Oye muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero si meto mas elementos al arreglo por ejemplo los registro 2 y 3, manda error o que estoy haciendo mal? Gracias por tus comentarios

Comment: Cierto. Ya actualicé la respuesta.